# Issue with sending SOAP request, through soapclient, to service that expects CDATA

Tags: php, soap-client, cdata

I am trying to make a SOAP request to a service that expects CDATA as part of the request. I managed to do successfull calls using Insomnia with the following, either of the two works:

```xml
    <ExecuteRequest xmlns="<url>">
      <TAG1>
            <![CDATA[
            <TAG2>
            <TAG3>TEXT1</TAG3>
            <TAG4>TEXT2</TAG3>
            <TAG5>TEXT3</TAG5>
            </TAG2>
                    ]]>
    </TAG1>
    </ExecuteRequest>
```

OR

```xml
    <ExecuteRequest xmlns="<url>">
      <TAG1>
            &lt;TAG2&gt;
            &lt;TAG3&gt;TEXT1&lt;/TAG3&gt;
            &lt;TAG4&gt;TEXT2&lt;/TAG4&gt;
            &lt;TAG5&gt;TEXT3&lt;/TAG5&gt;
            &lt;/TAG2&gt;
    </TAG1>
    </ExecuteRequest>
```

But I've been having trouble translating the above to work with the php soapclient. For example using the following:

```php
  $soapclient = new SoapClient('url?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
            $xmlWriter = new \XMLWriter();
            $xmlWriter->openMemory(); 
        
            $xmlWriter->startElement('TAG1');
                $xmlWriter->startElement('TAG2');

                $xmlWriter->writeElement('TAG3','TEXT1');
                $xmlWriter->writeElement('TAG4','TEXT2');
                $xmlWriter->writeElement('TAG5','TEXT3');
                
                $xmlWriter->endElement();
            $xmlWriter->endElement();


            $myXml = $xmlWriter->outputMemory(true);

            $params = array(
                new \SoapParam(new \SoapVar($myXml, XSD_ANYXML), 'param')
            );

            $response = $soapclient->__soapCall('ExecuteRequest',$params);

            $lastrequest = $soapclient->__getLastRequest();
```

$soapclient->__getLastRequest() gives me this output which obviously isn't what I want, no CDATA:

```xml
<TAG1>
    <TAG2>
        <TAG3>TEXT1</TAG3>
        <TAG4>TEXT2</TAG4>
        <TAG5>TEXT3</TAG5>
    </TAG2>
</TAG1>
```

If instead in the xmlwriter I use this to write the CDATA manually:

```php
$xmlWriter->writeCdata('<TAG2>
<TAG3>TEXT1</TAG3>
<TAG4>TEXT2</TAG4>
<TAG5>TEXT3</TAG5>
</TAG2>');
```

Then for some weird reason $soapclient->__getLastRequest() returns the CDATA section commented out and I can't figure out why that is happening:

```xml
<TAG1>
<!--[CDATA[<TAG2-->
<TAG3>TEXT1</TAG3>
<TAG4>TEXT2</TAG4>
<TAG5>TEXT3</TAG5>
""]]>"
</TAG1>
```

Notice how TAG2's closing tag is lost as well.

**EDIT**

The same issue with the CDATA being commented out happens if I don't use the xml writter.

```php
$wholeTag = new \SoapVar("<TAG1><![CDATA[{$text}]]></TAG1>", XSD_ANYXML);
$params = [
  'param' => $wholeTag,
];
```

Any ideas? It's very likely that I'm going about this in the wrong way, so I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: There are reserved characters which you cannot use within CDATA, unless it is commented out, like `<`, `&`, `'`, and `"`. Perhaps `writeCdata()` automatically comments the data out when these occur? Did you really use the data in your example, or is that just an example for this question?

Comment: Yes the data are real, just changed the names to be more generic.

Comment: If < was illegal then why it comments out the first line only but you may be right that something could be going on with that method.

Comment: I agree that commenting out only the first line doesn't make sense. It could be that method, but I'm not sure, that's why I used a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Edited the OP to add another scenario where the same issue happens.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting hours on this I ended up discarding using the soapclient altogether and solved it with Guzzle.

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException; 


$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement("<put the whole xml body here, using the Webservice's SOAP 1.1 sample as a reference>");             
 
$xmlstring = $xml->asXML();


$client = new Client();
        $url = "< the **full** webservice url (used the Webservice's SOAP 1.1 sample as reference)>";
        $action = "action url (used the Webservice's SOAP 1.1 sample as reference)";

   try {
            $response = $client->post($url, 
            ['headers' => 
                ['SOAPAction' => $action,
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                'Host' => "<host url (used the Webservice's SOAP 1.1 sample as reference)>"
                ],
            'body' => $xmlstring
            ]);
    }
    catch (GuzzleException $e) 
    {
        return [ 'status' => $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), 'message' => $e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase()];          
    }
    
    if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
        // Success!
        return $response->getBody();
    }
```